# Is The Quick Draw the Slowest Hat in The West?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winterbash

The description of the Quick Draw hat reads:

> Answer a Question within 5 minutes of it being asked.

I answered two questions in under 5 minutes today ([4:57](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42423/is-there-any-way-to-control-which-vehicles-i-get/42426#42426) and [3:00](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42442/can-saadia-be-married) respectively).

I have not received a Quick Draw hat. I see three possibilities:

- The delay that occurs before hats award is for some reason taking longer than normal, either for my account, or for this hat. *It has been over three hours since the first qualifying answer though, so this seems unlikely.*
- The Quick Draw Hat requires that said fast answer receive some number of up votes greater than 3, and/or that the answer be accepted to be awarded. *If this is the case the description is wrong, and should be updated.*
- The Quick Draw Hat is Broken. *If so, please fix it?*
- There is a conspiracy to deny me hats. It is hardcoded into the system that I will never be awarded more than <s>8</s>9 hats. *Uh-oh. Speculating publicly about that last one might not have been the be-*

Comment: Hat reeducation officers have been dispatched to your location.  Please assume the hat reeducation and relocation party position.

Comment: I think you must receive an upvote on your answer within the first 5 minutes of the question being asked with competing answers being posted too.  I have the hat and noticed that my quick answer received an upvote and _then_ I got the hat.

Comment: @agent86: You mean "the hat reeducation _submission_ position".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the above. The bug was somewhere else, but one of its consequences was the Quick Draw hat hat not being awarded. This is fixed now; everyone has their hats.

Except you. Because your point 4 is correct after all.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that it's not unlocking for me either; it was a close call, but I answered [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43903/how-do-i-make-christmas-last-all-year) within 4 minutes 50 seconds.

Comment: @lunboks: You're right; that was a bug. Fixed now; you have the hat now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer has to be accepted for you to get the hat.  That first one should have gotten you the hat, but the time was awfully close so I'm not sure.  It definitely took me a while before I was awarded the hat.

Comment: Acceptance isn't it. Ashley Nunn accepted my answer to the Jetpack Joyride question, and I have not yet been awarded a hat.

Comment: like I said, that answer was really close to the cutoff time, something weird might be going on